# Scroll snap not working, eventhough all elements are in place?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement scroll snap I think I have everything in place but it doesn't seem to work, i have tried it with overflow y and it didn't work and even did .scroll-test>* but that didn't work either, any help is greatly appreciated

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
    .scroll-test {
        overflow: scroll;
        scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    }
    
    section {
        scroll-snap-align: start;
    }

    .page1 {
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #202020;
    }

    .page2 {
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: red;
        scroll-snap-align: start;

    }

    .page3 {
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="scroll-test">
        <section class= "page1">
            page 1
        </section>
        <section class = "page2">
            Page 2
        </section>
        <section class = "page3">
            Page 3
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The height of the `.scroll-test` class should be `100vh`.

```css
.scroll-test {
  height: 100vh; /* You forgot this line! */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.page1 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #202020;
  color: #fff; /* For readability */
}

.page2 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f00;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.page3 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-test">
  <section class="page1">
    page 1
  </section>
  <section class="page2">
    page 2
  </section>
  <section class="page3">
    page3
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I found that out when few hours after posting the question but I want to know the reason why this happens?